# regular expression for skipping specific words

Tags: regex, keyword

I need to make a regular expression (I'm using notepad++ for searching text files) that matches all copyright lines without my company name:

// Copyright MyCompany

// Copyright OtherCompany

// Copyright OtherCompany2

It should match the second line & third line but not the first line. Is this possible at all?
(I've seen the discussion here: [Regular Expression to exclude set of Keywords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116819/regular-expression-to-exclude-set-of-keywords) but it doesn't seem to work in notepad++. Also, is it wrong to be using an editor for this?)

Comment: Forget about whether or not it's wrong to use an editor for it -- it's probably wrong to be doing it at all!  *Please* tell me you have express permission from the copyright holders...

Comment: I think "filters out" is the wrong phrase to use :). I meant "matches"

Comment: Notepad++'s regex support is seriously lacking. As far as I know, lookahead is not supported (which you'd need for this).

Comment: Can you tell me about other editors that support lookbehind & ahead?

Comment: It doesn't matter what you're calling it - if the purpose is to remove someone else's copyright, you aught to go question yourself.

Comment: Not trying to remove copyright. Just searching for source code that's not from my company

Comment: @Swaroop: Check out [EditPadPro](http://www.editpadpro.com). Best regex support on the market; version 7 coming out this month. And I'm not affiliated with that company.

Comment: @Tim: EditPad Pro v7 is already out.

Comment: @MRAB: Hey, great (I had checked the newsfeed which hadn't mention it yet). Thanks for the heads-up, though I'll wait until the German version is released.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest getting Cygwin if you are on Windows, otherwise just use the command line and go with

```
grep 'Copyright' theFile.txt | grep -v 'MyCompanyName' > theParsedFile.txt
```

EDIT: Modified to answer the question better.

Comment: I need to search for "Copyright " followed by anything OTHER than my company name

Answer (score 1):

`/Copyright[ \t]++(?!MyCompany)/i`

Would be the regex, but don't think that notepad++ has support for such regexes. If you install Perl you can use that regex with a one liner.