# Searching hard coded text in xcode

Tags: objective-c, search, xcode4, ios5

Hello I would like to localize my application, and the problem I have hard coded text all around the code also in the xib files.
I would like quick way to externalize or better to get all hard coded text and put it in external file .
if some one have done this before pls share ?

Answer (score 7):

You can use regular expression to search in all projects.

Press <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> and open global search.
Click on lens (on the left of textfield) and select "options".

Select Regular Expression and paste `@"[a-zA-Z0-9]+"`

[image]

hope this helps.

Comment: That expression may need a bit of fine tuning, for example it won't strings with any spaces, dashes, or punctuation. In this situation a regex of @"[^"]+" may be more useful.

Comment: can you please tell me the regex @"[^"]+" that exclude NSlog and exclude : at the begining ex isEqualToString:@"ffl  la ld" , thanks

Comment: i suggest this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116819/regular-expression-to-exclude-set-of-keywords

Comment: @Mark that regex messes up on empty strings. This is what you want: @"[^"]*" (drop the @ for swift)