# Find hardcoded strings but not those for file names (Xcode, Regex help)

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, xcode, string

I am searching for all hardcoded strings in my app so I can localize them.  Currently I am using the regular express search for @"[^"]+" as suggested in this answer:
[Searching hard coded text in xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9520040/searching-hard-coded-text-in-xcode)

The issue is I want to only find some strings in this format.  For example, I want to exclude [UIImage imageNamed:@"string"] and NSLog(@"Log string").  I believe the easiest way to do this is find a string of the format of @"[^"]+" as long as the prior characters do not include NSLog(, or imageNamed:, or several other things I will enter in manually.

How can I write a regex that excludes these cases?

Comment: What flavor regex does it use?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use a negative lookbehind to exclude those cases:

`(?<!(imageNamed:|NSLog\())@"[^"]+"`

Answer (score 5):

I think this would be more comprehensive

```
"[a-zA-Z0-9 ?!.,;/\-=+)(*&%#@]+"
```

Search > Find > Regular Expression -- type

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

For Swift project

In Xcode > Search > Find > Regular Expression -- type `"[a-zA-Z0-9]+"`

[image]