# How can I add a character at the end of a line in Vim only if the preceding word is not blacklisted

Tags: vim, editor, customization

So, in JavaScript I'd write something like:

`foo (function () {});`

Notice the semicolons. How, in Vim, can I have it automatically add the semi when I type the `(`. It'd act something like:

`foo(` or `foo (` then Vim auto completes the `)` and creates `foo ()`. Also automatically I want it to put a semicolon at the end like `foo ();` and put my cursor where it normally goes in-between the `foo(|)`.

I DONT want it to add tho if the word before it is: `while|if|else|else if|for|switch|function` since you wouldn't put a semicolon at the end of those. Basically, a list of reserved words.

Comment: Who is adding the `)`? -> (what's the output of  `:verb inor (` ?)

Comment: ~/.vim/plugin/autoclose.vim

Comment: You should try [Cosco.vim](https://github.com/lfilho/cosco.vim) plugin.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your question whether you're already using one of the *auto close* plugins that automatically insert a matching `)` once you type `(`, but your use case of adding the `;` is just a little extension of that algorithm.

[This Vim Tips Wiki page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Automatically_append_closing_characters) outlines how auto-close is implemented, and it has a list of plugins that implement this. I'd check those out; maybe one of them already provides your extension, or at least you can try to extend one of them to suit your needs.

Personally, I dislike too much automatism in that area. Even with clever rules, the auto-insertion cannot be right 100% of the time, and I find the distraction caused by those cases much worse than the little benefit of not having to type a simple character like `;`.

Answer (score 0):

you can do a search/replace command with regex containing words excluded.
So the search will be performed only when the line/pattern does not have any of the unwanted words ..
I have no idea how to build this regex but maybe this link will help you:
[Regular Expression to exclude set of Keywords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116819/regular-expression-to-exclude-set-of-keywords)