# Regexp: match and exclude

Tags: regex

In this list:

- image_1.png
- image_1_small.png
- image_2.png
- image_2_small.png
- image_three.png
- image_three_small.png
- antoher_image.png

I would like to match only those images that BEGIN with the word **image** BUT do not contain the word **small**.

The regex should then return:

- image_1.png
- image_2.png
- image_three.png

So far I have:

```
/^image(?!.*small)/m
```

Comment: Which language? And what's the issue?

Comment: Your Regex works. I changed it a bit so you grab the entire filename: [RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=^%28image%28%3F!.*small%29.*%29&input=image_1.png%0Aimage_1_small.png%0Aimage_2.png%0Aimage_2_small.png%0Aantoher_image.png)

Comment: @HamZa I noticed that you keep using `(?!.*small)`, why the `.*` before small ?. Isn't `(?!small)` enough ?

Comment: @Sniffer `(?!small)` will only prevent "imagesmall" from matching. It would still match "image_1_small".

Comment: @Robit: i'm using cakephp folder api (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/fr/core-utility-libraries/file-folder.html) to list files. It returned empty value.

Comment: If that's the list, just use `^image_\d+\.png$`, why do you have to intentionally exclude "Small", and what is the Math in this?  I think you could have a much more efficient solution if you gave more details.

Comment: @Suamere: i meant 'match' (edited). image_*small*.png are auto generated, so i don't want them to be shown in the user file manager. Your regex won't work because it should return ALL the images that begin with **image**, so it should match **image_three.png** too.

Comment: That makes sense then, throw that up in the question as one of the examples to match.

Answer (score 1):

I tested this with your single lines from the list

```
 ^image(?!.*_small.*).*\.png$
```

see also this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116819/regular-expression-to-exclude-set-of-keywords) on how to exclude keywords in regex