# trying to Exclude Strings from my Regex Search

Tags: regex

I'm using the following expression to filter Oracle Java vulnerabilities from a list. This works just fine:

```
^(?!.*Oracle Java.*).*$
```

I'm having a tough time adding another string to exclude.

I got the expression from an earlier question here:

[Regular Expression to exclude set of Keywords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116819/regular-expression-to-exclude-set-of-keywords/831989#831989?newreg=79572bd033da4de39c8785412c1232c1)

I've tried all the examples from this link but the answer Tim gave was the only one that worked for me.

Does anyone know how I could add another string to this?

```
^(?!.*Oracle Java.*).*$
```

Comment: What is the tool that you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex alternation inside the lookahead:

```
^(?!.*(Oracle Java|excluded1|excluded2).*).*$
```